# Scope of NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data

Will a `NSFetchedResultsController` work if a property of a entity it's observing gets changed?

For example, I have configured a `NSFetchedResultsController` for a class called `conversation`. Now this `conversation` can have an array of `messages`. Permissible operations on this property `messages` is Read/Unread or deleted.

So at some stage if I delete a message or mark one as read or update a message, will the state of the `Conversation` structure get dirty and will my original fetch results controller return the updated `conversation` value with the modified `messages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, the fetched results controller does not react to changes in attributes of relationship entities different from the entity of its main fetch request.

One solution is to have the Message entity issue its own `NSNotification` via notification center upon attribute change and have the view controller containing the fetched results controller listen to it.

Comment: I guess I am still not clear...Let me Re phrase it...FRC(Conversation). `Conversation` has a ordered set of `Message`. There is a separate FRC for message. When I add a message, the FRC springs into action for both `conversation` and `messages`/ But when I update the `message`, the FRC for for Conversation is silent. Is this precisely the expected behaviour because of the reason you outlined.

Comment: *Is this precisely the expected behaviour because of the reason you outlined[?]* Yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of `messages`, yes. If `messages` is a relationship however then some of the changes will cause updates (adding or deleting) and some won't (read or unread). This is because the FRC is tracking changes in the `Conversation`, not the `Message` entity.

The difference is if `Message` isn't an entity and you're using an Array then the `messages` are actually a binary blob of data and any change is completely on `Conversation`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Wain. My actual Data structure is this way. Conversation is a class and Messages are a NSOrderedSet(I presume this behaviour is similar in Coredata other than the obvious differences between array and set). My Problem is when my **messages** are updated, the FRC tracking **conversation** does not catch this. Whereas when my **conversation** is updated by adding a **message**, the FRC tracking messages is updated. SO would you suggest, the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: I mean do you thing the way my FRCs are configured are correct? Just to add Message is a separate entity and it has a relation with `conversation`

Comment: So you don't really have an array, you have a relationship. My answer still describes this situation. You need to track message changes separately, perhaps with another FRC...

Comment: I guess I am still not clear...Let me Re phrase it...FRC(Conversation). `Conversation` has a ordered set of `Message`. There is a separate FRC for message. When I add a message, the FRC springs into action for both `conversation` and `messages`/ But when I update the `message`, the FRC for for Conversation is silent. Is this precisely the expected behaviour because of the reason you outlined.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wain. Will mark your answer as answered. Additionally, just as an after thought, If when I update the message, I add the updated message back to the conversation, shouldn't this invoke the FRC on Conversation?

Comment: Well, you marked an answer :-) Yes, it most likely would as you would change the set index.